# Work with Modules & Route Limits in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am breaking down my mammoth application into smaller modules so that they can load up faster. I anticipate at least 20-25 various modules. Each module is individually developed and deployed to server directly. Eg: one for billing, one for frontend, one for API, one for mobile, 4-5 for backend tasks and lot more in similar fashion.

The bigger question is

- how do I work with 10 limit routes in dispatch files
- how do I work with 20 max modules per app?

I was thinking to move some of the modules (small components) to GCE so that they can use the same datastore. However, managing sessions will be an issue and the app logic has to be changed.

Comment: wow 25 modules do seem like a lot. I guess you could go around the max modue limit using different, but deploying and routing that would be a nightmare. Are do you really need to split bacjend tasks in more than 5 modules? are the settings so different?

Comment: there are over 40 devs working on various different items; it's fairly a very big app. But coming back to the point, why restrictions?

Comment: seems like more of a business decision than a tech limitation, probably to prevent people from overusing modules. Maybe write the GAE team stating your situation? you might get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Recently GAE rose the limit from 10 to 20 routing rules:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dispatchref

Yo can also use url's specifying the module to be used, e.g.
Sends a request to an available instance of the named service and version:

> https://version-dot-service-dot-app-id.appspot.com
>
> http://version.service.my-custom-domain.com